# Cambiar IDIOMA de TECLADO android

Tags: java, android

Actualmente me encuentro con que usando mi clase de MASCARA para los montos escritos , segun el telefono reacciona diferente , esta es mi clase de mascara

```
    public class Mask implements TextWatcher {

private DecimalFormat df;
private DecimalFormat dfnd;
private boolean hasFractionalPart;
private int trailingZeroCount;

private EditText et;

public Mask(EditText et)
{
    df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    this.et = et;
    hasFractionalPart = false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        int inilen, endlen;
        inilen = et.getText().length();

        String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
        Number n = df.parse(v);
        int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
        /*if (hasFractionalPart) {
            et.setText(df.format(n));
        } else {
            et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }*/
        if (hasFractionalPart) {
            StringBuilder trailingZeros = new StringBuilder();
            while (trailingZeroCount-- > 0)
                trailingZeros.append('0');
            et.setText(df.format(n) + trailingZeros.toString());
        } else {
            et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }

        endlen = et.getText().length();
        int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
        if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
            et.setSelection(sel);
        } else {
            // place cursor at the end?
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length() -1 );
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // do nothing?
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // do nothing?
    }

    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    int index = s.toString().indexOf(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()));
    trailingZeroCount = 0;
    if (index > -1)
    {
        for (index++; index < s.length(); index++) {
            if (s.charAt(index) == '0')
                trailingZeroCount++;
            else {
                trailingZeroCount = 0;
            }
        }

        hasFractionalPart = true;
    } else {
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }
    /*if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
    {
        hasFractionalPart = true;
    } else {
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }*/

}
```

Instale mi aplicacion en 2 telefonos que tengo yo un J5 2016 y un J7 Prime 2016

aqui las fotos pantallas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede apreciar en una de las fotos , si esta andando correcto marca los MILES con coma y los decimales con punto , pero en la otra marca los miles con punto por lo que no puedo ponerle comas para los decimales , y es la misma aplicacion instalada en 2 telefonos , por lo que me imagine que podria ser el idioma o algo de eso, hay alguna forma por medio de android studio de decirle que use X region o idioma , desde ya gracias

Comment: y te has asegurado que los dos smartphone tienen la misma región e idioma ?

Comment: si de eso ya estoy seguro

Comment: Entonces no es problema de eso ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con esta librería que te permite asignarle una máscara al EditText y no la tienes que hacer tu a mano:

compile 'br.com.jansenfelipe:androidmask:1.0.1'

Tienes que descargar el .jar de aquí he incluirlo en la carpeta ☻lib:

https://github.com/jansenfelipe/androidmask/tree/master/app/dist

Para utilizarlo, sólo tienes que hacer esto:

```
EditText etPrueba;
etPrueba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETprueba);

MaskEditTextChangedListener maskCPF = new 
MaskEditTextChangedListener("#,###.##", etPrueba);

etPrueba.addTextChangedListener(maskCPF);
```

Espero que solucione tu problema.

Información obtenida de: https://jansenfelipe.com.br/2015/05/08/android-como-inserir-mascara-em-um-edittext/

Comment: Despues  de pensar que deberia ser la region y eso , me di cuenta que es porque los telefonos tenian diferente IDIOMA de teclado , aunque agradesco tu respuesta ,

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag entonces edita tu pregunta indicado que solo es el idioma que necesitas cambiar